# EC2 instance needs php-7.3 to be default version

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which was running PHP 7.0 and was upgraded to 7.3, where if I run `php -v` I get:

```
PHP 7.3.30 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2021 20:34:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.30, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.30, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

However, when I run `sudo alternatives --config php` I get:

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'php'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/bin/php-7.0
 + 2           /usr/bin/php-7.3

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2
```

... which shows 7.0 still being the default, and choosing number 2 does NOT update the default version

Asking then, if there's another way of making version 7.3 the default php version for the instance. Note: the type of linux is relevant here:

````
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"```
````

Comment: running the commands as the ec2-user should put the php7.3 as default.

`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php-7.3;sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar-7.3`

you can confirm if the default version has been changed or not by using the phpinfo() query.

Answer (score 0):

First think first, you can uninstall PHP 7.0. Maybe permanently delete it. If you dont want to do that, try to run `export PATH=/path/to/your/php/bin:$PATH` to select one version as default. good luck~!